# Internate Explorer Compatibility Issue

Tags: ie-compatibility-mode

My Webpages are behaving differently in IE-7, IE-8, IE-8 Compatibility Mode and IE-9. Navigation from one page another is not taking place in few versions of IE and styles are not getting applied on few versions. What should I add into my code so that my Webpages opens properly in all the versions of IE.

Answer (score 0):

do you have

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

at the top of the page with no extra line?

Comment: I have the following one                                               <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">